# How to filter a schema based on other schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have 2 Schemas

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const {ObjectId} = mongoose.Schema;

const matchList = new Schema({
    user:[{
        type: ObjectId,
        ref:'User'
    }]
});


const user = new Schema({
    name:{
        type:String
    }
});
```

**matchlist contains a user field which is an array of userId from user schema.
how can I get all the users from the user Schema whose id is not in the matchlist collections?**

Answer (score 0):

first you get a document from the matchList collection.

```
const _matchList = matchList.findOne();
```

Next, you filter users collection with the `$nin` operator to filter by an array, in this case the array of ObjectId.

```
const _usersNotMatch = user.find({ _id: { $nin: _matchList.user }}).
```

Then you have the users whose id not in the matchlist collections